# How to detect retina screen?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using MVC 4.5 ...

I'm trying to prepare my website for retina screens.

How can I from codebehind (code on server) detect, if user has a Retina screen?

I would prefer not to do it from java, but from code on server.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. BTW, You don't need to "detect a retina screen". You can use [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) to support different style sheets for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Retina Display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display) is a brand name and not tightly defined.  It sounds like you want to detect whether it is a newer version of iPad or not.  Details on detecting those are widespread.

Comment: I need to figue out, if my... <img src="myimage.png" height="80"> ... actually should be 80 pixels high or 160 pixels high to look good on retina screens (screens with double aspect ratio).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function(){
  if( document.cookie.indexOf('device_pixel_ratio') == -1
      && 'devicePixelRatio' in window
      && window.devicePixelRatio == 2 ){

    document.cookie = 'device_pixel_ratio=' + window.devicePixelRatio + ';';
    window.location.reload();
  }
})();
```

Comment: that's javascript